# git commit - N/A" is not yet installed

Tags: git, nvm

I am having this issue with committing to git. There were no problems such as this until now.

I can just go `rm -rf .git` and do all the setup and then the `git commit` works just fine, but then I do something for couple of hours, try to commit and again, this message.

Should I just go and install the nvm they are asking me to install? Are there any consequences?

```
MacBook-Pro-3:testing NYC$ git commit -m "X"
Found '/Users/NYC/Desktop/testing/frontend/.nvmrc' with version <v6.11.1>
N/A: version "v6.11.1 -> N/A" is not yet installed.

You need to run "nvm install v6.11.1" to install it before using it.
Found '/Users/NYC/Desktop/testing/frontend/.nvmrc' with version <v6.11.1>
N/A: version "v6.11.1 -> N/A" is not yet installed.

You need to run "nvm install v6.11.1" to install it before using it.
husky > npm run -s precommit (node v8.2.1)

Error: fatal: Not a git repository: '.git'

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/NYC/Desktop/testing/frontend/node_modules/staged-git-files/index.js:85:19)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:921:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:348:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:549:12)

husky > pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)
```

Answer (score 1):

(nvm maintainer here)

The `nvm` issue seems like it's because you have an `.nvmrc` file, but you also have chosen to hijack `cd` (or you have a git hook that does it) and automatically call `nvm use`.

The precommit hooks are part of `husky`, an entirely different tool that deals with git commit hooks.

First, I'd run `nvm install`, just to ensure that the node version it's asking for is installed.

Then, I'd check `.git/hooks` and audit the git hooks you have installed.

After that, things should be working a bit better.